# how to call method on load in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hope everythign is fine.

I am new to flutter.

I want to call a method on load ?

I tired

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    log('Load Event');
  }
```

But it is not working ?

Any chance

Here is my full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo ',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();


}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Position _currentPosition;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Trex Partner Finder hh"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("assets/images/TrexIcon.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            ),
          ),

        ),
      floatingActionButton:
      FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          _getCurrentLocation();
        },
        label: Text("                     Find Partner Alooo                 "),

      ),
    );
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    log('h');
  }



  _getCurrentLocation() {
    final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    log(_currentPosition.longitude.toString());
    log(_currentPosition.latitude.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding the overide annotation like   ```@override
  void initState() {
    print('h');
    super.initState();
  }```

Comment: @TinusJackson not owrking

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b minimal product with just the initstate and its working

Comment: @TinusJackson Can I detect if position is changed

Comment: @TinusJackson  How can Listen if application is closed

Answer (score 8):

Put your mathod in `initState`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo ',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();


}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

   @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
   _getCurrentLocation();
  } 

  Position _currentPosition;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Trex Partner Finder hh"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("assets/images/TrexIcon.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            ),
          ),

        ),
      floatingActionButton:
      FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {},
        label: Text("                     Find Partner Alooo                 "),

      ),
    );
  }



  _getCurrentLocation() {
    final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
    geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    log(_currentPosition.longitude.toString());
    log(_currentPosition.latitude.toString());
  }
}
```

for more info about `initState` [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

Comment: @ A R it worked but how can I get the location of device on load

Comment: @ A R How can Listen if application is closed

Comment: You have to Implement Android LifeCycle

Answer (score 0):

```
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      print('hi there');

      // Or call your function here
    }
```

should work